# Retrieve multiple rows using IN operator using Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have created a webpage in ASP.net using C#. This page retrieves data from Oracle 11g database.In this page I have put one Text Box and at the time of running the page I use to enter the number in the Text Box and accordingly data retrieves from the database.

Please Refer my code :-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.31.41.103/ORCL;User ID=RL_PET;Password=RL_PET;Unicode=True");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT PALLET_NO,MERGE,RES_WT,GROUP_ID,RACK_NO,WH_CD,DATA_STS,SCAN_DT,INPUT_DT,MPNSEQ_NO,MPN_DT FROM WI_PALLET WHERE PALLET_NO IN ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')", con);
    a.Fill(ds);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        string display = "Please Enter Pallet No...!!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

    }
    else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        string display = "Please check Pallet No...!!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I passed values 95403355,95403354,95403353 in Text Box still data not retrieves from database.
I know its not retrieving because it consider all the input as whole and try to search in database.

My question is any solution like escape sequence so that I can retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `"PALLET_NO IN ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')"` turns into `PALLET_NO IN ('95403355,95403354,95403353')` where `'95403355,95403354,95403353'` is single varchar2 expression. Just check quotes in your code. If `PALLET_NO` is number, then remove single quotes from in-expression.

Comment: It will be static then.

Comment: What do you mean about the static? I'am about `IN (" + TextBox1.Text + ")"` instead `IN ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another temporary variable, put textbox value in it as:

```
 string filter = "'" + TextBox1.Text.Replace(",","','") + "'";
```

Your query could become like this:

```
 OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT PALLET_NO,MERGE,RES_WT,GROUP_ID,RACK_NO,WH_CD,DATA_STS,SCAN_DT,INPUT_DT,MPNSEQ_NO,MPN_DT FROM WI_PALLET WHERE PALLET_NO IN (" + filter + ")", con);
```

Comment: retrieving last record only.